# Variable not sent to server with IE

Tags: php, html, laravel, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using checkboxes on one page on my website and I'm trying to be able to see the checked one(s) with PHP.

Here's the code:

```
<input id=checkBoxChrome form="saveform" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Chrome" checked >
```

And the associated PHP:

```
public function save(Request $request) {
    if (count($request->checkbox) == 0) {
        \Session::flash ( 'error', 'Choose one browser minimum' );
        return Redirect::back();
    }

    $this->saving($request);

    $this->saveConfigs($request);

    \Session::flash ( 'success', 'Scenario saved.' );

    return redirect ( '/testscenarios' );
}
```

On Firefox and Chrome this code returns a success but it returns an error on IE. After some investigation I found that $request->checkbox returns the checkboxes in Chrome and Firefox, but nothing with IE.

Any idea why?

The command `dd($request->all());` gives me the following result:

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "TfE0jjLcxsAc69kWjTPAVL9BfJBTBjPILJP2rDqm"
  "scenario" => "6"
  "scripts" => "[[{"id":18,"elementid":51,"token":"","deleted":false},{"id":16,"elementid":52,"token":"","deleted":false}]]"
]
```

Comment: Could you dump the content of request: `dd($request->all());` at first line of `save()` method for IE? (and copy/paste the content here)

Comment: Could you replace your input by: `<input id="checkBoxChrome" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Chrome" checked="checked">` and try again?

Comment: Did you set `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your HTML? This could cause a problem when using older IE version...

Comment: This problem occurs with the last IE version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found where the problem was coming from! The attribute `form="saveform"` is not supported by IE (HTML5) and it is with the two other browsers.